# Do not place Android context classes in static fields

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to access to the context of an application, but doing it this way it says "Do not place Android context classes in static fields" on the third line. Tried to remove the `private val` but without it I can't access to the context on the copyDatabase function.

I need the context to copy a database in the assets folder to the data folder of the application.

```
class Database constructor(private val ctx: Context) : ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(ctx, "dex.db", null, 1) {
    companion object {
        private var instance: Database? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(ctx: Context): Database {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Database(ctx.applicationContext)
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }    

    private fun copyDatabase() {
        val input = ctx.assets.open("databases/dex.db")
        FileOutputStream(ctx.getDatabasePath("dex.db").path).use { out ->
            input.copyTo(out)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Some asides: you are using a broken double-checking lazy init idiom, replace with `by lazy { ... }`. Also no need for the word `constructor` there, it's assumed

Answer (score 2):

By using a `companion object`, whose lifetime equals the lifetime of the loaded `Database` class, you have created a lifecycle mismatch between the `Context` you capture in the database instance and the database instance itself.

When your application is put to background and restored, or if you just rotate the device, the context (typically the `Activity` instance) will be destroyed without destroying the whole application, so the database instance will survive with a disposed context. This will reliably lead to application failure.

Although you *could* be careful to use an `Application` context instead, which would most probably match the lifecycle, the general practice of retaining the context instance is ill-advised, hence the warning.

Instead put the database instance as a property of your main activity class, or, alternatively, commit to using a dependency injection framework that will deal with this as a separate concern.

As an aside, your current code uses a broken variant of the double-checking lazy initialization idiom. If you need lazy initialization, in Kotlin you should always leave this to the `by lazy` property delegate instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the `Context` inside a `static` variable prevent the garbage collector to free the memory afterwards and will lead to a memory leak. You should pass a `Context` to your constructor and initialize everything inside it and should not have to retain it inside a variable.

Comment: How will this work, then? `val input = ctx.assets.open("databases/dex.db")` Apparently it's called from somewhere, later on.